# Removing a property inside an object using destructuring

Tags: javascript

My teacher asked me to create a function to remove the property 'password' inside each object using the destructuring method, but I think he was fooling me cause I haven't found a way to do so.

```
const test = [
    {  
      email: "samu@kenzie.com",
        endereco: { rua: "Rua Quitino", bairro: "Nações", zipCode: "78120-000"} ,
      id: 1,
        idade: 26,
      nome: "Samuel Persuhn",
      password: "51686aaasd2",
      stacks: [ "JavaScript", "PostgreSQL", "Node.js" ]
      },
  
    {
        email: "patrick@kenzie.com",
      endereco: { rua: "Avenida São Paulo", bairro: "Centro", zipCode: "45687-000"},
        id: 2,
      idade: 22,
      nome: "Patrick Nekel",
      password: "supersenha123548",
      stacks: [ "JavaScript", "MongoDB", "Python" ]
      },
    {  
      email: "samueleao@kenzie.com",
        endereco: { rua: "Avenida Brasil", bairro: "Centro", zipCode: "4587-000"},
        id: 3,
      idade: 28,
      nome: "Samuel Leão",
      password: "hash*asdasda7788",
      stacks: [ "HTML5", "CSS3", "React.js" ]
      },
    {
        email: "danrley@kenzie.com",
      endereco: { rua: "Rua do videomaker", bairro: "Hollywood", zipCode: "44744-000"},
        id: 4,
      idade: 30,
      nome: "Danrley",
      password: "889977",
      stacks: [ "VideoMaker", "Effects", "Roteirista" ]
      }
]
```

I tried using destructuring inside each object as if each parameter was an array but it didn't work out

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the data to return a new array of objects. For each object [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the password, and assign all the other object properties to another object using the [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). Then just return that object.

```js
const test=[{email:"samu@kenzie.com",endereco:{rua:"Rua Quitino",bairro:"Nações",zipCode:"78120-000"},id:1,idade:26,nome:"Samuel Persuhn",password:"51686aaasd2",stacks:["JavaScript","PostgreSQL","Node.js"]},{email:"patrick@kenzie.com",endereco:{rua:"Avenida São Paulo",bairro:"Centro",zipCode:"45687-000"},id:2,idade:22,nome:"Patrick Nekel",password:"supersenha123548",stacks:["JavaScript","MongoDB","Python"]},{email:"samueleao@kenzie.com",endereco:{rua:"Avenida Brasil",bairro:"Centro",zipCode:"4587-000"},id:3,idade:28,nome:"Samuel Leão",password:"hash*asdasda7788",stacks:["HTML5","CSS3","React.js"]},{email:"danrley@kenzie.com",endereco:{rua:"Rua do videomaker",bairro:"Hollywood",zipCode:"44744-000"},id:4,idade:30,nome:"Danrley",password:"889977",stacks:["VideoMaker","Effects","Roteirista"]}];

// `map` over the data and for each object
// destructure out the password, and assign the
// rest of the properties to a new object (I've called
// it `rest` here but you can call it anything. Finally
// return that object
const out = test.map(obj => {
  const { password, ...rest } = obj;
  return rest;
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop around the array, destruct the object of each and only get only the properties you need:

```js
let test = [
    {  
      email: "samu@kenzie.com",
        endereco: { rua: "Rua Quitino", bairro: "Nações", zipCode: "78120-000"} ,
      id: 1,
        idade: 26,
      nome: "Samuel Persuhn",
      password: "51686aaasd2",
      stacks: [ "JavaScript", "PostgreSQL", "Node.js" ]
      },
  
    {
        email: "patrick@kenzie.com",
      endereco: { rua: "Avenida São Paulo", bairro: "Centro", zipCode: "45687-000"},
        id: 2,
      idade: 22,
      nome: "Patrick Nekel",
      password: "supersenha123548",
      stacks: [ "JavaScript", "MongoDB", "Python" ]
      },
    {  
      email: "samueleao@kenzie.com",
        endereco: { rua: "Avenida Brasil", bairro: "Centro", zipCode: "4587-000"},
        id: 3,
      idade: 28,
      nome: "Samuel Leão",
      password: "hash*asdasda7788",
      stacks: [ "HTML5", "CSS3", "React.js" ]
      },
    {
        email: "danrley@kenzie.com",
      endereco: { rua: "Rua do videomaker", bairro: "Hollywood", zipCode: "44744-000"},
        id: 4,
      idade: 30,
      nome: "Danrley",
      password: "889977",
      stacks: [ "VideoMaker", "Effects", "Roteirista" ]
      }
];

test = test.map(({ email, id, idade, nome, stacks }) => ({
  email, id, idade, nome, stacks,
}));
```

Comment: You haven't used any destructuring. Your answer also mutates the data which might not be what the OP wants. And if you're going to use this approach `forEach` is a better method - `map` returns an array while `forEach` works in-place.

Comment: @Andy I have updated my answer and applied destructing. Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeItem(){
    const newTest = test.map(({email, nome, id, stacks, idade, password}, index) => {
        return {email, nome, id, stacks, idade}
    })
    
    return newTest;
}
```

you wont need to remove or delete as removing any item from list will mutate.